# Gradle build in docker Jenkins agent

Tags: docker, gradle, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to create a Jenkins agent for building gradle lambda projects. Jenkins agent is throwing the below error while building the project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create parent directory for lock file /gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.2.1-bin/dajvke9o8kmaxbu0kc5gcgeju/gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip.lck
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:43)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
/home/jenkins/workspace/ddoa-subprod/lf-security-gateway2/lf-security-gateway2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
```

Please help me in understanding the issue and let me know how to fix the same.

Comment: try delete gradle cache folder

Comment: Looks like it can't create the .gradle directory inside your workspace. Could be a permission issue. Try running with --info or --debug to see if it tells you the exact error.
tyr `sudo gradle`

Answer (score 3):

To fix this error: `What went wrong: Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.` do the following:

1. Check if your Gradle cache (**~user/.gradle/**native folder exist at all or not).
2. Check if your Gradle cache (**~user/.gradle/native** folder exist and the file in question i.e. `libnative-platform.so` exists in that directory or not).
3. Check if the above folder ***~user/.gradle*** or ***~/.gradle/native*** or file: ***~/.gradle/native/libnative-platform.so*** has **valid permissions** (should **not** be read-only. Running `chmod -R 755 ~/.gradle` is enough).

IF you don't see native folder at all or if your native folder seems corrupted, run your  Gradle task ex: `gradle clean build` using `-g` or `--gradle-user-home` option and pass it's value.

**Ex:** If I ran `mkdir /tmp/newG_H_Folder; gradle clean build -g /tmp/newG_H_Folder`, you'll see Gradle will populate all the required folder/files (that it needs to run even before running any task or any option) are now in this new Gradle Home folder (i.e. **/tmp/newG_H_Folder/.gradle** directory).

From this folder, you can copy - **just** the ***native*** folder to your user's ~/.gradle folder (take backup of existing native folder in ~/.gradle first if you want to) if it already exists -or copy the whole ***.gradle*** folder to your ~ (home directory).

Then rerun your Gradle task and it won't error out anymore.

**Gradle docs says:**
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html

**-g, --gradle-user-home**
Specifies the Gradle user home directory. The default is the .gradle directory in the user’s home directory.

Note: using `gradle <sometask> -g <a_dynamic_folder_ex_jenkins_workspace>` will always work as Gradle will create fresh .gradle cache in that `-g` defined folder, but doing this, it'll not reap the true benefit of Gradle's cache concept.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version 3.4 if Gradle, then it could possibly be [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1493).

To fix it, you can try to update your Gradle distribution to version 3.5 or higher, where this issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command as sudo and it went through fine

Comment: where do you add sudo on jenkins?